# Parse JSON in UNIX date in Java/Android without any library

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON array received from my server. I obtain a date as a timestamp String – for example, `[{"date": "1418056895", ... }]` – and I need to parse it in our day format. How do I do this? I have tried but I always have the year as 1970.

Note: My JSON format is in UNIX.

```
JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);
FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("date"));


public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

public String getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}
```

In another class, I parse the timestamp to display it:

```
List<FeedItem> feedItems = ...;
FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
           System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
```

However the displayed date is always in 1970.

Using values such as `1403375851930` it appears to work as expected (it displays a contemporary date).

Comment: why do you use `getRelativeTimeSpanString`?

Comment: I want to convert to human readeble format

Comment: I dont know in the tutorial was it

Comment: and what exactly is not working? What is your question?

Comment: i got this data so I want to convert it like 8.12.2014 but when I get it from Json its like date":1418056895

Comment: but its work with "timeStamp": "1403375851930" but not in my case

Comment: in my case i get 17.02.1970

Comment: Your timestamp is in seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66493/discussion-between-sultan-and-njzk2).

Comment: @Michael Myers i cant ask any question how to be?I know I have 2 questions with minus and others positive

Comment: @Sultan: Deleting negative questions doesn't remove them entirely. When you attempted to ask a question, you should have seen a message telling you what was happening and what to do about it. If for some reason you didn't, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: @Michael Myers  thats mean I should have positive questions?that can be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are parsing JSON correctly,

```
feedObj.getString("date");
```

holds your date. You are reading date as String. You have to convert it to long.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Long timestamp = Long.parseLong("1418056895"); //Long.parseLong(feedObj.getString("date"));
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp * 1000L);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // what ever format you need.
    System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime())); // this will be in MM/dd/yyyy
    //item.setTimeStamp(format.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

you can also use **feedObj.getLong("date")**; to get Date in long format directly, but it depends on which JSON library you using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to ask here. But if you're asking is to ow to convert that date that you get in human readable form then you should take a look at [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/). The date is returned to you in epoch timestamp. You can convert the same to a human readable form n java by using the following code.

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));
```

Comment: how to use it with json

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your api documentation and the date you have in response is in unix time format as described here [wall.post](http://vk.com/dev/post)

You can convert it using the method described here [Convert Unix time stamp to date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java)

Once converted you can format the date as described below.

```
 private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
TextView timestamp
 FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
Long timeObject = Long.parseLong(getTimeStamp());

//use the timeObject and convert it in the String as described
// in above link to convert timestamp in date object than in String

//Once available set it again in timestamp
timestamp.setText(formattedDate);
```